# Using excel vba to copy specific file extensions to another folder using the FSO method

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to use fso technique to copy from source folder C:\ ( V) to target folder C:(All) but running code **give message runtime error 53. file not found**

What I am trying to achieve is to copy all xlsx file from source folder C:\ V which contains also other file extension pdf, csv, txt, word..

All xlsx will be copied to folder C:\ALL,

Getting runtime error on this line below

****FSO.CopyFile Source:=sourcePath & fileExtn, Destination:=destinationPath****

```
Sub copy_specific_files_in_folder()




Dim FSO As Object
Dim sourcePath As String
Dim destinationPath As String
Dim fileExtn As String

sourcePath = "c:\V"

destinationPath = "c:\all\"


fileExtn = " * .xlsx"


If Right(sourcePath, 1) <> "\" Then
sourcePath = sourcePath & "\"
End If

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If FSO.FolderExists(sourcePath) = False Then

MsgBox sourcePath & " does not exit"

Exit Sub

End If

If FSO.FolderExists(destinationPath) = False Then
MsgBox destinationPath & " does not exit"

Exit Sub
End If

FSO.CopyFile Source:=sourcePath & fileExtn, Destination:=destinationPath

copy_files_from_subfolders

MsgBox "your files have been copied from subfolders of " & sourcePath & "to" & destinationPath



End Sub




Sub copy_files_from_subfolders()

Dim FSO As Object, fld As Object
Dim fsoFile As Object
Dim fsoFol As Object

sourcePath = "c:\V"

targetpath = "c:\all\"


If Right(sourcePath, 1) <> “ \ ” Then sourcePath = sourcePath & “ \ ”

Set FSO = CreateObject(“scripting.filesystemobject”)
Set fld = FSO.GetFolder(sourcePath)
If FSO.FolderExists(fld) Then
For Each fsoFol In FSO.GetFolder(sourcePath).SubFolders
For Each fsoFile In fsoFol.Files
If Right(fsoFile, 4) = “xlsx” Then
fsoFile.Copy targetpath
End If
Next
Next
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi change `fileExtn = " * .xlsx"` to `fileExtn = "*.xlsx"` and that should fix your issue.

**EDIT**

The code below should fix your other sub procedure.

```
Sub copy_files_from_subfolders()

Dim FSO As Object, fld As Object
Dim fsoFile As Object
Dim fsoFol As Object

sourcePath = "c:\V"

targetpath = "c:\all\"


If Right(sourcePath, 1) <> "\" Then sourcePath = sourcePath & "\"

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set fld = FSO.GetFolder(sourcePath)
If FSO.FolderExists(fld) Then
For Each fsoFol In FSO.GetFolder(sourcePath).SubFolders
For Each fsoFile In fsoFol.Files
If Right(fsoFile, 4) = “xlsx” Then
fsoFile.Copy targetpath
End If
Next
Next
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Change as per your post but get compile error , variable not defined "Sub copy_files_from_subfolders()" sourcePath = "c:\V"

Comment: That would be a different issue and I believe it is connected to your `copy_files_from_subfolders()`sub procedure. I have edited my answer and try copy the new code for the copy_files_from_subfolders. If you still get an error exclude from your code first and make sure the copying works.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked "Sub copy_specific_files_in_foldera()" works, it copies all files in main directory from c:\v to  c:\all but in applying your edit . I get compile error message variable not defined **sourcePath** . the "Sub copy_files_from_subfolders()" in yellow.

```
Sub copy_specific_files_in_foldera()
```

Dim FSO As Object
Dim sourcePath As String
Dim destinationPath As String
Dim fileExtn As String

sourcePath = "c:\V"

destinationPath = "c:\all\"

fileExtn = "*.xlsx"

If Right(sourcePath, 1) <> "\" Then
sourcePath = sourcePath & "\"
End If

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If FSO.FolderExists(sourcePath) = False Then

MsgBox sourcePath & " does not exit"

Exit Sub

End If

If FSO.FolderExists(destinationPath) = False Then
MsgBox destinationPath & " does not exit"

Exit Sub
End If

FSO.CopyFile Source:=sourcePath & fileExtn, Destination:=destinationPath

'copy_files_from_subfolders 'suspend'

MsgBox "your files have been copied from subfolders of " & sourcePath & "to" & destinationPath

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Generally too much hard-coding in the functions/subs.

Keep the variables as inputs:
I have added a Reference to Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime

```
Sub CopyFiles(extension As String, sourceFolder As String, targetFolder As String, recursive As Boolean)
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim src As folder, dest As folder

    Set src = fso.GetFolder(sourceFolder)
    Set dest = fso.GetFolder(targetFolder)

    Dim srcFile As File
    For Each srcFile In src.Files
        Dim srcFilepath As String
        srcFilepath = srcFile.Path
        If Right(srcFilepath, Len(srcFilepath) - InStrRev(srcFilepath, ".") + 1) = extension Then   'extension includes the "."
            srcFile.Copy targetFolder, True 'I set Overwrite to True
        End If
    Next srcFile

    If recursive Then   'If recursive is True then will go through all subfolders recursively
        Dim subDir As folder
        For Each subDir In src.SubFolders
            CopyFiles extension, subDir.Path, targetFolder, True
        Next subDir
    End If
End Sub

Sub testCopy()
    CopyFiles ".xlsm", "C:\Source", "C:\Destination\", True
End Sub
```